# Decrypting image file in with Java AES/ECB

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

For an assignment, we have to decrypt 5 encrypted picture files. 
The assignment has given us the key: {"2b 7e 15 16 28 ae d2 a6 ab f7 15 88 09 cf 4f 3c"}: with the parameters that the files were padded and that
1.The file size is represented in 8 bytes, where the first byte is the most significant byte. 
2.The size of the padding is the number of bytes needed to make [file_size+padding_size+8] a multiple of 16. 
3.The bytes passed for encryption are: original_file, padding, file_size.

Here is my code below:

```
enter code here public class AESEncryption {

public static String algo = "AES";
public static String transformation = "AES/ECB/NoPadding";
public static String key = "2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c";
public static String path = "AESencrypt_1.jpg";

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException {
    //encrypt();
    decrypt();
    bytes();
}

    private static void encrypt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException{
   Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
   byte[] b = key.getBytes();
   SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(b,"AES");
           aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
    CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("ecrypted.jpg"), aesCipher);

    copy(is, os);
    os.close();
```

}
        `

```
    private static void decrypt()throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,           NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException{

    byte[] b = key.getBytes();


             //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    //CipherInputStream is = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream("AESencrypt_1.jpg"), aesCipher);
    //CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream("decPic.jpg");
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(path);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Decrypted.jpg");
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);

       SecretKeySpec key1 = new SecretKeySpec(b,"AES");
               aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key1);
    CipherOutputStream outSt = new CipherOutputStream(out,aesCipher);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read=file.read(buf))!=-1){
        outSt.write(buf, 0, read);

    }

    file.close();
    out.flush();
    outSt.flush();
```

}

```
private static void copy(InputStream cin, OutputStream fos) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i;
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    while((i=cin.read(b))!=-1) {
        fos.write(b, 0, i);
    }
  }
}
```

My code accepts the input stream and saves the new output file but the image is still unreadable. I am not sure if I am not passing the key the correct way or if I need to remove the padding in order to see the image. If I do, can you point me in the right direction please? Thank you.

Comment: It is more likely than not that the key you are displaying is the hex-encoded version of the true 16 byte AES key. Instead, you are treating like 32 character string.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. I cannot believe it was that simple. Now I used: ` byte[] convertHexString = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(key);
  String newKey = new String(convertHexString);
      byte[] keyByte = newKey.getBytes(); `      is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @Deviance I've written a Hex decoder for java.util but I haven't submitted it. There is a Java hex decoder in Java Commons Codec, Google Guava and Bouncy Castle and undoubtedly countless other libraries.